# android reverse geocoding not working on huawei device

Tags: java, android, reverse-geocoding, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to reverse Geocode lat,long by this piece of code

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            return addresses;
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
    }
```

Its working on all devices except Huawei.It is giving exception in Huawei device. Client reported on his huawei device, Huawei Y625 running on kitkat. I tested it on huawei H30 running kitkat and its not working also. However running on all other devices tested inc Samsung, Nexus etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the logcat ? any stack-trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Huawei mobiles will not support GMS Map Services it will support HMS Map Services only .

Comment: android.location.Geocoder is not a part of GMS. it's core component

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with some android devices and the geocoder not working:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

A reboot seems to fix the issue.